# MVC Entity framework from local database to SQL database Azure

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, localdb

Possibly a very simple question, but it has already taken me several days. The problem:

In my project, MVC Entity framework, and on my local computer it connects with a local database and that works as expected. I can add items to the database and remove its etc. At azure, I have a SQL database and when I deploy the project to azure I get the following error message

```
network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - 
Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL 
Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime 
feature is enabled.)]
```

I ques that the my connection string is incorrectly and my application can't connect to the azure SQL database. I tried to add and change the connection string, but somehow I can't make it work. This is what I have (minus password and username) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings><add name="InventoryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Administration.csdl|res://*/Administration.ssdl|res://*/Administration.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=****;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/

Comment: Have you tried connecting and pointing to the Azure SQL Database will debugging locally? Does that work fine?

Answer (score 0):

After a night sleep, I finally got it working.First of all, I had to make clear which database I was going to be use where the DbContext was initialized

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{

    public EFDbContext() : base("name=InventoryEntities")
    {

    }
}
```

With InventoryEntities being the name of the connectionstring in the web.config of the WebUI which I did not change.

Simple as that, but it took days......